# ControlPaint.Light changes Orange to Magenta

Tags: .net, rgb

I want to make a lighter version of some colors. But Orange (and other colors) is giving me problems.
When I use System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Light with 50% it will change the color to Magenta.

```
Color color1 = Color.Orange;
Color color2 = ControlPaint.Light(color1, 50f);
```

This results in ffff5ee7,  {Color [A=255, R=255, G=94, B=231]}, which is Magenta.

How can I use ControlPaint.Light to actually create light orange not Magenta?

(This is happening to some other colors I am lightening, and I am not using named colors, but ARGB values.  I used the named color here as an example.)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in that your are using `50f` for your Percentage instead of `.5f`. The documentation does not state it but  according to this [MSDN Forum posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/7a2e9080-e7fa-4ea5-8656-ad2f9c80c5f0)  you should be using 0 to 1 for your values.

Comment: Thanks.  The MSDN help lists the parameter as: percOfLightLight
The percentage to lighten the specified Color.  This was confusing.  Also it seems that I need a number > 1.0 to have the lightening effect I required.

Comment: @Matt You are welcome, that is why I linked to the MSDN post.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the MSDN help is confusing and even wrong.
I developed this code...

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Makes the color lighter by the given factor (0 = no change, 1 = white).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">The color to make lighter.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to make the color lighter (0 = no change, 1 = white).</param>
    /// <returns>The lighter color.</returns>
    public static Color Light( this Color color, float factor )
    {
        float min = 0.001f;
        float max = 1.999f;
        return System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Light( color, min + factor.MinMax( 0f, 1f ) * ( max - min ) );
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the color darker by the given factor (0 = no change, 1 = black).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">The color to make darker.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to make the color darker (0 = no change, 1 = black).</param>
    /// <returns>The darker color.</returns>
    public static Color Dark( this Color color, float factor )
    {
        float min = -0.5f;
        float max = 1f;
        return System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Dark( color, min + factor.MinMax( 0f, 1f ) * ( max - min ) );
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Lightness of the color between black (-1) and white (+1).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">The color to change the lightness.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor (-1 = black ... +1 = white) to change the lightness.</param>
    /// <returns>The color with the changed lightness.</returns>
    public static Color Lightness( this Color color, float factor )
    {
        factor = factor.MinMax( -1f, 1f );
        return factor < 0f ? color.Dark( -factor ) : color.Light( factor );
    }

    public static float MinMax( this float value, float min, float max )
    {
        return Math.Min( Math.Max( value, min ), max );
    }
```